# Android: How to use bold text inside normal text

Tags: android, layout, text

I have the following TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This must be bold (but not this)" />
```

I want only a part of the text to be bold. `android:textStyle="bold"` will therefore not work.

Answer (score 2):

If the text is coming from a string resource, use `<b>` tags as you would in HTML:

```
<string name="foo"><b>This must be bold</b> (but not this)</string>
```

If the text is coming from somewhere else, use a `SpannableStringBuilder` to wrap the bold portion in [a `StyleSpan`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/StyleSpan.html) set for boldface. Or, generate an HTML edition of the string with `<b>` tags and use `Html.fromHtml()` to create the `Spanned`. In either case, the `Spanned`/`SpannableStringBuilder` output then just gets passed to `setText()`, which will rendered the desired portion in bold.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it but I think it is very handy with xml therefore you can create a string in html and do it like this:

`String sourceString = "<b>" + id + "</b> " + name; 
mytextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(sourceString));`

Where id and name will be two different text in your class